# Is there a online reference that chains mathematical knowledge from simple to complex?

Tags: education, learning

I'm a very, very logical person -- but I've never taken any math classes; really, I know.

So, on that note -- how do I teach myself math? As my question might suggest, I see the answer as being an online reference that chains mathematical knowledge from simple to complex -- but I'm open to other suggestions. One thing that would be of interest is if the resource had a rating on the complexity/depth of knowledge required to reach an understanding of the given concept; yes, unlikely, but doesn't hurt to ask.

Questions, feedback, comments -- just comment, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning maths is like building, all foundations must be down before the next level.  So the first question you need to answer well is: **"What do I understand already?"** (note the use of *understand*, not *know*)

Once you know where you are at, then you can find the next level up, if your level is under that taught in regular schools you should be able to identify your level roughly by grade (probably per domain: number, geometry, etc.) and move up from there.  If you are already up to a degree level, then finding a natural path ahead is more subjective matter, there is much to cover but many routes.

Perhaps expand your question with your current opinion of your level to get more accurate help.

Comment: @Orbling: +1 Thanks for posting. To answer your question, I really do know nothing beyond ad-doc info; meaning if I was to take a math test, I'd fail even on basic knowledge questions. That said, my interest is as stated, a resource that will help me access and gauge the requirements related to a given topic. For example, I would not see the basics of said reference as 1+1, but as the axioms of math; which paradoxical proves I know more about math than most people that know nothing about math. I really am looking for what I'm looking for as stated.

Comment: @: On an unrelated note, find it very, very interesting that you've up-voted 267 questions (0 down votes) -- and aside from my question, never asked or answered any other questions... :-) ...at least on math.stackexchange -- so, again, thanks for posting! (FYI, just recalled I don't have the rep here to up vote an answer to my own question, oh, well. +1 in spirit...)

Comment: @blunders: Well, I'm quite active on other SE sites, and always read through the Maths.SE stuff, I've taught maths up to A-Level standard and have done a lot within my own domain at higher levels.  But most of the questions here are degree level Maths, I like to read what is said and learn from it, but can not usually contribute.  I rarely ask questions anywhere, just answer.

Comment: @blunders: In the UK, the BBC have a site called [Bitesize](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/), it has various levels corresponding to the five keystages of compulsory education [KS1 (ages 5-7), KS2 (ages 8-11), KS3 (ages 12-14), KS4/GCSE (ages 15-16)] with tests, recaps and such like. It is a useful measuring stick - I tend to start people on the GCSE or KS3 tests and see if they handle them fine and move up or down from there.  No idea if it is accessible in your region however.

Comment: @Orbling: Cool, Bitesize, while not what I was thinking would be an answer is viewable from the States, and looks like a great starting point -- thanks. Also, we've run across each other before... again, thanks for sharing!! http://www.google.com/search?q=%2BOrbling+%2Bblunders

Comment: @blunders: Glad it might be of interest, I find it very useful for assessing adult mathematical capability.  Most adults I find somewhere between KS2 and KS3 capability, which should be age ranges 7-14, but reflects the general adult range.  Obviously there are exceptions for people who are highly educated in a related field or use more advanced mathematics in their work, but the rank and file are about that level; and yes, I get around. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the exercises at [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/) may be useful. They have exercises in mathematics ranging from basic arithmetic to advanced calculus that gradually build your way up, as well as lectures and practice questions to help check your progress.